# How can I change the collations in my MySQL 5.6 DB to utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql, collation, utf8mb4

I have in my DB (MySQL 5.6 in a shared hosting server) several collations and I want to set all of them to utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation and also change the connection charset to utf8mb4

How can I do it using phpMyAdmin for my DB without going table by table?

Thanks!
Ram

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you have to do it table by table.  However you can write a single SQL to generate all the `ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO ..` statements, then copy&paste them.

Caution:  Since you are in 5.6 (or 5.5), you may hit the dreaded "767" (or MyISAM's "1000") limit, primarily if you have `VARCHAR(255)`.  Here are 5 workarounds:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes  (That link also has a sample of such a `SELECT`.)

If your tables are currently MyISAM, you really should change to InnoDB.  Tack this onto the `ALTERs`:  `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

For conversion to InnoDB, see  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Hi, I did it in 2 steps:

SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', tbl.`TABLE_NAME`, '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;') FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` tbl WHERE tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'DB_NAME'

I got a long list of that I copied to the SQL again - but I got this error:

#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

So as far as I understand from the link you added before I should Upgrade to 5.7.7... - right?

Comment: @Ram: 255*4 > 1000.  Either _first_ change 255 to 250 where relevant (and safe).  Or pick a suitable workaround in my list.  If you do go to InnoDB, then 250 will still be a problem, so you really should go to **191** if possible.  (I added to my Answer.)